# org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The column index is out of range:

Tags: java, jdbc

I am using spring JDBC Template,

```
    Map resultsMap = getStoryJdbcTemplate().call(
    new CallableStatementCreator() {

      public CallableStatement createCallableStatement(Connection pConn)
          throws SQLException {
        CallableStatement callable = pConn.prepareCall(DELETE_STORY);
        callable.setLong(1, pStory.getId());
        callable.setLong(2, pStory.getVersion());
        callable.registerOutParameter(3, Types.INTEGER);
        callable.registerOutParameter(4, Types.BIGINT);
        return callable;
      }
    },
    Arrays.asList(new SqlParameter[] { new SqlParameter(Types.BIGINT), 
        new SqlParameter(Types.BIGINT),
        new SqlOutParameter("rowCount", Types.INTEGER), 
        new SqlOutParameter("version", Types.BIGINT) }));
```

When I executed following query, I got The column index is out of range: 1, number of columns: 0.; nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException.

```
    private static final String DELETE_STORY = ""

+"Do $$"      
+ "DECLARE "
+ "   v_rowcount numeric; "
+ "   v_version numeric; "
+ "BEGIN "
+ "     DELETE FROM registrant_stories "
+ "     WHERE registrant_story_id = ? AND version = ? "
+ "     RETURNING version INTO v_version; "
+ "     GET DIAGNOSTICS v_rowcount := ROW_COUNT; "
+ "     ? := v_rowcount; "
+ "     ? := v_version; "
+ "END $$ ; ";
```

Error trace is:

```
   org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: CallableStatementCallback; SQL []; The column index is out of range: 1, number of columns: 0.; nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The column index is out of range: 1, number of columns: 0.
at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLStateSQLExceptionTranslator.doTranslate(SQLStateSQLExceptionTranslator.java:100)
```

Thanx, Please help me out..

Comment: As the `DO` block is not a procedure, I guess you cannot use CallableStatement. Try using a regular PrepareStatement and then `execute()` instead. CallableStatement is strictly for stored procedures if I'm not mistaken.

Answer (score 1):

The error message means you are expecting more columns then you were returned.